# IIS + UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewrite: Overwrite existing URL?

Tags: iis, rewrite

I'm trying to over-ride default behavior in my CMS, but without hacking the core or doing anything outright barbarous. As a result I'm trying to rewrite all requests to

```
/umbraco/dialogs/preview.aspx?whatever
```

so they'll end up at

```
/IveySuperPreview/IveySuperPreview.aspx?whatever
```

It seems that UrlRewritingNet only grabs on to URL's that don't exist as real pages, though. I can rewrite, for example, /umbraco/dialogs/preview_test.aspx – but if I try it on the actual preview.aspx, nothing happens.

Am I correct that this is what's going on? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Try URL Rewrite module (IIS 7.0+)-- should rewrite **any** url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have (more thoroughly) [RTFM](http://www.urlrewriting.net/Download.ashx?File=4640f315-27ae-4ab0-8930-6957cfd1f138)'d:

> ### Attributes for <urlrewritingnet />
>
> **rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls**
>
> *true, false (Standard: true)*
>
> Prevents rewriting for real existing files on the server if true.